# Use Supabase .select with Sveltekit store

Tags: sveltekit, supabase

if in my current .svelte file i have

```
let todos = [];

onMount(async () => {
let { data, error } = await supabase .from('todos') .select('*')
todos = data;
```

however i don't think that's pretty efficient,

in my store.js file, should it be written as

```
export const todos = writable([])

export const loadTodos = async() => {
let { data, error } = await supabase
.from('todos')
.select('*')
todos = data;
}
```

Im not sure if that is even correct but, If so, how do i call it back into my .svelte file to load ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is meaningless; if you remove the information that is already available in the tags, your title is *and Store*. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future user of the site who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem, and your current title is totally void of any content.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i made an edit

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer for it

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
import supabase from '$lib/db';

export const todos = writable([]);


export const getTodos = async () => {
    let { data, error } = await supabase.from('todos').select('*');
    if (!error) {
        todos.set(data);
    }
};
```

and in the svelte file.

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { todos, getTodos } from '$lib/stores/test';
    getTodos();
</script>

<div>
    {#each $todos as task}
        {task.task}
        
    {/each}
</div>
```

now to figure out how to delete and update